# Python socket server port forwarding with ngrok

Tags: python, sockets, portforwarding, ngrok

I am making a cli-chat system with python, sockets.
When the server and client are in the same machine, the code works fine.

But now I am trying to port forward my local server with ngrok, to chat with remote clients.

When the client wants to connect he would have to give the server url. If I am giving my localhost url, client connects to the socket server and everything works fine.

But whenever I am giving the ngrok's tcp tunnel url, it doesn't works and throws the error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Sun/Python/cmd-chat/user.py", line 5, in <module>
    client.connect((serverUrl, 5000))              #connecting client to server
socket.gaierror: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname
```

The url I am giving as input is,
`tcp://x.tcp.ngrok.io:17xxx`

Comment: The argument to `connect` is not a URL but host and port, i.e. `("x.tcp.ngrok.io",17xxx)`

Comment: I also wonder if `pyngrok` might help you with some of this, as it's a native Python wrapper around `ngrok`. The docs also have a socket/client example. https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I think I got where you are going wrong

```py
# Your Server Url should be
serverUrl = hostAddress = "x.tcp.ngrok.io"

# The Port in which we want to connect to the server Should be
port = 17234 # The number given in the end of URL link
```